# $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb Z((t))$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, power-series, formal-completions

Consider  the ring of formal Laurent power series $\mathbb Z((t))$ and let $p$ be a prime. Let $(p)$ be the ideal in $\mathbb Z((t))$ generated by $p$:

1. What is an explicit expression of the $(p)$-adic completion of $\mathbb Z((t))$?
2. Let $A$ be the  completed ring obtained in 1. What is its fraction field?

Comment: Given $\Bbb{Z}_p=\varprojlim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb{Z} / (p^n)$ then $\varprojlim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb{Z}[[t]][t^{-1}] / (p^n) = \ ?$

Comment: 1. seems to be $\mathbb Z_p((t))$.

Comment: Question 2. is harder, it is not the obvious answer.

Comment: Yes the fraction field should be bigger than $\mathbb Q_p((t))$

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_p((t))$ is a subring it won't be bigger

Comment: For the question 1, if $\mathbb{Z}_p((t))$ means $\mathbb{Z}_p[\![t]\!][t^{-1}]$, then I think something is missed: for example those of the form $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}a_nt^n$ with $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ satisfying $\lim_{n\to -\infty}{a_n}=0$ (for the $p$-adic topology) should also be included in the $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Z}[\![t]\!][t^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Frac(\Bbb{Z}_p[[t]])$ is a subfield of the field $$F=\{t^{-N} p^{-m} \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n  p^{-nk} t^n \in \Bbb{Q}_p((t)), a_n \in \Bbb{Z}_p,N,m,k \in \Bbb{Z}\}$$

I'd say $Frac(\Bbb{Z}_p[[t]]) $ is still smaller than $F $ and that there is no easy characterization of the formal series in $ \Bbb{Q}_p((t))$ that are quotients of two elements of $Frac(\Bbb{Z}_p[[t]])$

Comment: you mean $Frac(\mathbb Z_p((t)))$?